# What is the difference between Tachikoma and Fuchikoma?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell

What is the difference between Tachikoma and Fuchikoma? The Tachikoma's design was inspired by the Fuchikoma ([stated here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Ghost_in_the_Shell#Think_tanks)), but what are the differences between them? How is a Tachikoma different from a Fuchikoma?

Comment: I retagged the question, because it's not SAC-only, as the Fuchikomas only appear in the graphic novel.

Comment: Now there's also Logikoma from Arise series. Maybe this question can be updated to also include info on them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, the Tachikoma was introduced because of license-issues - the Fuchikoma couldn't be used in the SAC.

The main difference is the design: While the Fuchikomas had only one lense, the Tachikomas have 4 independent "eyes". Also, the Tachikomas are a little bit taller than the Fuchikomas.

[image: Tachikoma]
[image: Fuchikoma]

Also, the AI is a little bit improved, which leads to the fact, that Tachikomas are more human-like and also defend their human partners more. In SAC, it can be seen, that the Tachikomas don't mind risk and are happy most of the time, while the Fuchikomas were more serious.